# What does "bzr check" do?

Tags: version-control, command, bazaar

I recently saw the Bazaar command `check`, but not really sure what exactly it checks or verifies.  Can anyone give me some info?

Comment: Here is the man page for linux bzr command (It Validates working tree structure, branch consistency and repository history):  http://linux.die.net/man/1/bzr

Comment: I see but what kind of validation/consistency check is it. I mean what exactly does it do to achieve those ? Sorry I am bit new to version control :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**More info on what "bzr check" does, how it works and examples:**

This command checks various invariants about branch and repository storage to detect data corruption or bzr bugs.  The working tree and branch checks will only give output if a problem is detected.

http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.dev/en/user-reference/check-help.html

If you want to get down into the nitty gritty of how it does the corruption checks, I guess you could checkout the source code and start reading:

http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/SourceDownloads